# Sort the result of a group by - Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have documents like that

```
{"name":"Name_29","date":"2017-04-26","id":"ID_0","version":1}
```

And I try to have the last version of a document before a given date. ( version restart at zero on each date ).

I'm trying to perfome this kind of request

```
SELECT * 
FROM docs 
WHERE date <= '2018-02-03' 
    AND id = 'x'
ORDER by date DESC, version DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

But for and all a range of name.

```
SELECT RAW ARRAY_AGG({'name':name, 'id' : id ,'version' : version, 'date' : date}) 
FROM doc  
WHERE date <= '2017-02-27'
  AND name = 'NAME_02' 
GROUP BY id
```

But I'm strugling to extract the greatest date version of the array.

Is there any good and efficient practice to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit: what results would you like to see? What are you trying to show with the `SELECT RAW ARRAY_AGG` query?

Comment: I'm trying to have all document in there latest version before a given date. I' tried to used Array_AGG to have a simili map reduce function.
``` groupBy(id) then reduce( keep the last version )```

Comment: Okay, but that didn't work the way you wanted? What you want is to select all the documents, but only one per id field, and only the latest version number. I'll take a crack at this later, but I think you'll need to use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX([date,version,doc])[2]
FROM doc
WHERE date <= '2017-02-27'
  AND name = 'NAME_02'
GROUP BY id;
```

Check following link for explanation.
[couchbase N1ql query select with non-group by fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223030/couchbase-n1ql-query-select-with-non-group-by-fields/50238036#50238036)